# Acessing resource of a maven dependency in a wicket application

Tags: java, maven, wicket

I have two maven projects.

**components:** Contains wicket components. All of these wicket components rely on a single stylesheet called `component.css`. The stylesheet is generated by the libsass-maven-plugin and output to the `projet.build.directory`. (Directly into the target folder) This project is packaged as a jar.

**web-app:** This is the project for the (wicket) web application packaged as a war.

My problem is, that I just can't find a way to include the `componet.css` as a external resource in my **web-app** project.

I tried to include it into the webapp folder using the maven-war-plugin and loading it as a `<link>` inside the html, but that didn't work, because **components** isn't a war project.

Then I tried to use `new CssResourceReference(SomeClass.class, "/component.css")` to let wicket generate the `<link>` element, but I get an error that the access to (static) package resource is denied.

My last possible solution was to create a class inside **components** and generate the `component.css` relative to that class. But somehow even this isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I tried to use new CssResourceReference(SomeClass.class, "/component.css") to let wicket generate the  element, but I get an error that the access to (static) package resource is denied.

This should work. Wicket's default settings allow `.css` static files to be served [1]. Do you use a custom IPackageResourceGuard that disables `.css` ?

1. https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/PackageResourceGuard.java

Comment: Thank you martin for you're quick answer. I am using the default resourceguard, but after some testing I found out that `/css/component.css` isn't blocked while `/component.css` is. So I changed the output folder for the generated `component.css` to `css/component.css` and tried loading this with `new CssResourceReference(someClass, "/css/component.css")`. This caused a 404 on the frontend, even through `PackageResource#getResourceStream()` returned a stream with the correct data. As a last attempt I tried mounting the resource to a specific path and it worked.

Comment: files in root directory of resource folder are blocked by default, iirc you can disable that block.